# How do I replace one or more whitespace characters using the replace() function in XQuery?

Tags: regex, xquery

I need to replace multiple whitespace characters with a single dash in XQuery using the replace() function.

```
$input: 'abc   def   123'
Desired Output: 'abc-def-123'
```

I tried:

```
replace($input, '/s*', '-')
```

and

```
replace($input, '/s.*', '-')
```

but these do not work.  I am aware of normalize-space() but I want a more general function.

Thanks! - Dan

Comment: Shouldn't it be `replace($input '\s+', '-')`?

Comment: Right!  That worked.  I was using a forward slash!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the slash the wrong way round:

```
replace($input, '\s*', '-')
```

<strike>Also, depending on the implementation in XQuery, this might insert a dash between every two non-space characters (as `\s*` allows 0 characters, and therefore any empty match).</strike>

[**EDIT:** As Oliver Hallam points out in a comment, the [XQuery specification](http://w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) actually requires that an error is raised if the pattern can lead to zero-length matches.]

Therefore, you might want/have to use `+` (which means 1 or more characters) instead:

```
replace($input, '\s+', '-')
```

Btw, your other attempt (with the fixed slash) would match a single whitespace character plus anything that comes after it.

Comment: According to the specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) the query processor should throw an error in the first case - "An error is raised [err:FORX0003] if the pattern matches a zero-length string".  If your processor doesn't do this you've found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Two additional solutions:

**A simple XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
translate(normalize-space($vInput), ' ', '-')
```

**And an XPath 2.0 expression that replaces not only groups of spaces, but also groups of any punctuation or separator characters**:

```
replace($vInput, '(\p{P}|\p{Z})+', '-')
```